# How do I fix this error? (undefined reference to 'display_menu')

Tags: c, compiler-errors

The error  `undefined reference to 'display_menu` keeps persisting and I don't know why.

My `main.c` is:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include "care.h"

int main()
{
    display_menu();

    return 0;
}
```

My `care.c` is:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include "care.h"

void display_menu()
{

//some code defining display_menu

}
```

And lastly, my `care.h` is:

```
#ifndef __CARE_H__
#define __CARE_H__


void display_menu();

#endif
```

It seems quite right, but it wouldn't compile. Help?

Comment: what compiler do you use?

Comment: have you compile both files and linked together?

Comment: Are you sure it's a compiler error and not a linker error? Suggest you post the full error message.

Comment: In C, when a function have no arguments, you should really use `void`. Just empty parentheses means that the function have an unknown number of unknown arguments.

Comment: Works for me: gcc main.c care.c. Here is the gcc version: 
i686-apple-darwin10-gcc-4.2.1 (GCC) 4.2.1 (Apple Inc. build 5646) (dot 1)

Comment: "care.h" is in current directory ??? i.e main.c and care.h in same folder??.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you have multiple source files, you need to compile and *link* all source files. If you are using an IDE (such as VisualStudio, Eclipse etc.) then this should be handled by the IDE.

If you are compiling from the command line, you have to do this yourself instead.

Using GCC as an example:

```
$ gcc -Wall main.c care.c -o my_example_program
```

The above command compiles and links all source files on the command line into the program executable `my_example_program`. The option `-Wall` enables more warnings, which is good since many warnings can give you hints about possible bugs that might be technically legal but still do bad things. The option `-o` tells GCC what to name the result, in this case the executable program.

---

You can also split this up in multiple steps, compiling each source file into an object file, and then link all the object files together to the final executable:

```
$ gcc -Wall main.c -c -o main.o
$ gcc -Wall care.c -c -o care.o
$ gcc main.o care.o -o my_example_program
```

The option `-c` is the one that tells GCC to generate an object file instead of an executable. As before `-o` is what to name the resulting file, be it object file or executable program.

When you have a lot of files, this last way can become cumbersome, but there are tools such as [`make`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Make_%28software%29) which can help with this.